# Get Action/Controller name from context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

Can I get current **Action/Controller name** in **SignalR hub** like it is possible in usual MVC controllers using `HttpContext`?

Currently I am using:

```
if (HttpContext.Current != null)
    return HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
```

But this only returns something like:

http://localhost:5226/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=...&connectionData=...name...xhub...name...yhub...&tid=1

Also the `HubCallerContext` does not seem to have further information.

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that I could use [SignalR's Hub pipeline](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#hubpipeline):

```cs
public class LoggingPipelineModule : HubPipelineModule 
{ 
    protected override bool OnBeforeIncoming(IHubIncomingInvokerContext context) 
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Invoking '{0}.{1}({2})'.",
            context.MethodDescriptor.Hub.Name,
            context.MethodDescriptor.Name,
            string.Join(", ", context.Args));

        return base.OnBeforeIncoming(context); 
    }
}
```

That way I can set Action/Controller to a global object and access later on. This is of course not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

You could try getting the values from the [RouteData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routedata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object

```
       var controller = HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
       var action = HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't work for me as RouteData does not contain action/controller when in signalr hub.